# Resolving named datacontext component from Windsor Container

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor

I have two registration in container:

```
container.Register(Component.For<DataContext>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
container.Register(Component.For<DataContext>().LifestyleTransient().Named("transientContext"));
```

I have tried to resolve the named instance(transient) like this:

```
  var instance = Container.Instance.Resolve<DataContext>("transientContext");
  instance.Table1.Add(new Table1());
  instance.SaveChanges();
```

but at the SaveChanges() was thrown an exception "invalid operation. the connection is closed."

What could be the problem?

THX!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that Windsor is mixing up 2 of its resolve methods:

```
Container.Instance.Resolve<T>(object argumentAsAnonymousType) //the one its calling
Container.Instance.Resolve<T>(string key) //the one it should be calling
```

Windsor is then treating your key "transientContext" as an argument for the DataContext. The argument for the DataContext is a connection string ref which causes entity framework to throw the given exception. To resolve you can probably use a named argument:

```
var instance = Container.Instance.Resolve<DataContext>(key: "transientContext");
```